# Running a Kinect + Pandaboard and getting RVIZ on a remote

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, pandaboard, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04(ARMHF) and Hydro on a Pandaboard. I have been unsuccessful with the openni stack - rostopic list  shows one /tf topic and I can't seem to access any of the data within.

The freenect drivers seem better -  I am getting a bunch of topics and I can use imageview on the remote to get both rgb and depth fields.

Where I get stuck is in using rviz.  I don't know what to pick to view to get a simulated scan like on the turtlebot.  I seem to recall something about transforms but I am fuzzy on the details.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120816/running-a-kinect-+-pandaboard-and-getting-rviz-on-a-remote/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you're looking for the [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan) node.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0